# COTson linux installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, g++, package

I'm new in linux, and i know that this should be a stupid question, but i didn't find anything over the internet, so i decide to ask it here:

During the configuration of the COTson program using this line of code it gives me an error:

CODE: `./configure --simnow_dir ../simnow-linux64-4.6.2pub`

ERROR :

```
Cleaning temporary directory: /home/user/add-image_tmp_dir
* bootstrap.status is present
* WARNING: problems detected in bootstrap.status
* Run again bootstrap.sh
* Checking the cotson directory ...
* COTSon directory for images already exist.
* Tuning /etc/sysctl.conf...
*   Total RAM Memory system     = about 2 GB
*   mapoptim   = 0
*   mapmin     = 4194304
*   mapok      = 4194304
*   mapconfig  = 4194304
*   mapcurrent = 4194304
* Detected that VM configuration is ok: vm.max_map_count = 4194304
* Detected Distribution 'Ubuntu' - Version 'raring'
* Ubuntu raring supported
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
* Checking if extra packages should be installed ...
  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 

*** NOTE: for this step (installation of missing packages/dependencies: g++-multilib bison flex vnc4server rxvt xfwm4 xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi zsh sharutils build-essential xvnc4viewer screen liblua5.1-0-dev zlib1g-dev indent xutils-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbd-pg-perl gnuplot libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev lzma gnuplot-x11 procmail rpcbind gawk mc quota libpqxx3-dev ruby rubygems libopenssl-ruby libsqlite3-ruby ), either ask your admin or be sure you have sudo access
* Installing missing packages/dependencies...
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
* Packages installation FINISHED
* Checking ruby gems
sudo: gem: command not found
* Installing missing gems
* Checking connection befor to install ruby test-unit
* Connection OK
* Installing rubygems test-unit
sudo: gem: command not found
* Gems installation FINISHED

ERROR: Could not install one or more of g++ g++-multilib subversion genisoimage bison flex vnc4server  rxvt xfwm4 xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi zsh sharutils build-essential xvnc4viewer screen liblua5.1-0 liblua5.1-0-dev zlib1g-dev indent xutils-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbd-pg-perl gnuplot libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev lzma libxcursor1 libxrender1 libsm6 libxi6 libfontconfig1 gnuplot-x11 subversion procmail rpcbind genisoimage gawk gedit mc quota libpqxx3-dev ruby ruby1.8 rubygems libopenssl-ruby libsqlite3-ruby 
- Please check your distribution and edit 'configure' to reflect it
* ERROR: bootstrap.sh KO
```

Here is the guide that i follow to reach this point (from page 13):

[Teraflux_COTson_installation_guide](http://teraflux.eu/sites/default/files/TERAFLUX-D75-v17.pdf)

I understand that i need to install some packages but how can i get them?

For more details just ask

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

i try with the code given by @Scott Stensland but when it start to install the packages it give me this error:

ERROR:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libruby' instead of 'libopenssl-ruby'
g++ is already the newest version.
libxi6 is already the newest version.
ruby1.8 is already the newest version.
subversion is already the newest version.
gedit is already the newest version.
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version.
libxrender1 is already the newest version.
genisoimage is already the newest version.
liblua5.1-0 is already the newest version.
libsm6 is already the newest version.
libxcursor1 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5) but it is not going to be installed
 g++-multilib : Depends: gcc-multilib (>= 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: g++-4.6-multilib (>= 4.6.3-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 liblua5.1-0-dev : Depends: liblua5.1-0 (= 5.1.4-12ubuntu1.1) but 5.1.5-4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libreadline-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libtool
 libpqxx3-dev : Depends: libpq-dev (>= 8.0.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.2) but 3.7.15.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.2) but 3.7.15.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i try to solve it using `sudo apt-get install -f packagename`and `sudo apt-get autoclean $$ apt-get clear cache` but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is just a cut N paste from your msg with the install syntax in front

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y g++ g++-multilib subversion genisoimage bison flex vnc4server  rxvt xfwm4 xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi zsh sharutils build-essential xvnc4viewer screen liblua5.1-0 liblua5.1-0-dev zlib1g-dev indent xutils-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbd-pg-perl gnuplot libboost-dev libboost-thread-dev lzma libxcursor1 libxrender1 libsm6 libxi6 libfontconfig1 gnuplot-x11 subversion procmail rpcbind genisoimage gawk gedit mc quota libpqxx3-dev ruby ruby1.8 rubygems libopenssl-ruby libsqlite3-ruby
```

that will give you the missing packages

UPdate 1

> Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

when you google above message you mentioned the first link is https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages  which points to the next command you should issue ... go ahead and issue what it suggests as its top answer then re-issue the commands I list above

Comment: Thanks for answering. I try with your code, but some packages can't be installed, i posted an UPDATE in the main question so you can see the dependencies problems.